# How to update content in HTML by generating data from array objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and hope that I can get some guide here.
So, my task is to update the content in a HTML block when a corresponding option is selected.
I need to use 2 functions in the javascript given to generate the content from the javascript containing object arrays.
I have set up the codes for selecting an option from the dropbox and it works well. The problem is I need to update the info ( movie's name from movies.js , the datetime and house ) of the corresponding cinema. Whenever I choose a cinema, the contents have to be changed according to the cinema selected. I tried to run a loop and it really seems stupid and failed as expected. How can I edit my codes so that the contents can be updated when a corresponding option(cinema) is selected ? THANK YOU for your time and your helps are much appreciated. I am stuck at this step for a really long time :(

This is my code (selecting a related cinema) and I tried to run the loop but failed :( :

```html
<div id="Cinema">
<form id="cin" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cinema</legend>
            <select id="cinemaSelect">
                <option value="default"></option>   
            </select> 
            <script>
                var select = document.getElementById("cinemaSelect");
                for(var i=0; i < cinemas.length; i++){
                    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
                    txt = document.createTextNode(cinemas[i].branchName);
                        option.appendChild(txt);
                    select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
                    }
            </script>
        </fieldset>  
</form> 
</div>
<div id="lm">
<script>       
        function getMovieName(movieArray, id) {             
            for (let i=0; i<movieArray.length; i++) {                 
                if (movieArray[i].id == id) return movieArray[i].name;             
                }             
                return undefined;         
            }                     
            for (let i=0; i<cinemas.length; i++) {    
                let selected = document.getElementById("cinemaSelect").value;
                if (selected == cinemas[i].branchName){         
                    for (let j=0; j<cinemas[i].movies.length; j++) { 
                        let img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src= getMovieName(movies, cinemas[i].movies[j].id).thumbnail;
                        document.getElementById("lm").appendChild(img);
                        let aaa = document.createElement("P");
                        aaa.innerHTML = getMovieName(movies, cinemas[i].movies[j].id);
                        document.getElementById("lm").appendChild(aaa);                                         
                            for (let k=0; k<cinemas[i].movies[j].shows.length; k++) { 
                                let bbb = document.createElement("P");                   
                                bbb.innerHTML = "datetime  " + cinemas[i].movies[j].shows[k].datetime + "<br/>" + "House" + cinemas[i].movies[j].shows[k].house;               
                                document.getElementById("lm").appendChild(bbb);                                     
                            }  
                    }                   
                }         
            }  
    </script> 
</div>
```

For cinema.js, the array given is :

```js
function getCinemas() {
    return [
        {
            branchName:"City Cinema - New York",
            movies:[
                {   id:1,
                    shows:[
                    {   
                        index:1,
                        datetime:"8 Nov, Sun - 9:00am",
                        house:3            
                    },
                    {   
                        index:2,
                        datetime:"10 Nov, Tue - 11:00am",
                        house:3            
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {   id:2,
                    shows:[
                    {   
                        index:3,
                        datetime:"9 Nov, Mon - 2:00pm",
                        house:1            
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            branchName:"City Cinema - Los Angeles",
            movies:[
                {
                    id:2,
                    shows:[
                        {
                            index:4,
                            datetime:"11 Nov, Wed - 9:00am",
                            house:4
                        },
                        {
                            index:5,
                            datetime:"11 Nov, Wed - 11:00am",
                            house:2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            branchName:"City Cinema - Wisconsin",
            movies:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    shows:[
                        {
                            index:6,
                            datetime:"11 Nov, Wed - 9:00am",
                            house:4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For movies.js, the array given is :

```js
function getMovies() {
    return  [
        {
            id:1,
            type:"now",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../yy.mp4",
            name:"Casablanca",
            cast:"Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergmen",
            director:"Michael Curtiz",
            duration: 120
        },
        {
            id:2,
            type:"now",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../xx.mp4",
            name:"Chocalate",
            cast:"Christiano Roland, Wayne Beckman",
            director:"Alex Curtis",
            duration: 110
        },
        {
            id:3,
            type:"now",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../xx.mp4",
            name:"Wildlife",
            cast:"Marcus Randford",
            director:"David De Geek",
            duration: 100
        },
        {
            id:4,
            type:"upcoming",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../xx.mp4",
            name:"Barbecue",
            cast:"Taylor Watson",
            director:"Rolando Broom",
            duration: 105
        },
        {
            id:5,
            type:"upcoming",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../xx.mp4",
            name:"BigBuck",
            cast:"Mark Hughes",
            director:"Tim Carlton",
            duration: 115
        },
        {
            id:6,
            type:"upcoming",
            thumbnail:"../xx.png",
            src:"../xx.mp4",
            name:"Nature",
            cast:"Benjamin Crook",
            director:"Memphis Delan",
            duration: 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to  learn some JS tricks...

```js
  const Cinemas = 
      [ { branchName: "City Cinema - New York"
        , movies: 
          [ { id: 1, shows: 
              [ { index: 1, datetime: "8 Nov, Sun - 9:00am",   house: 3 } 
              , { index: 2, datetime: "10 Nov, Tue - 11:00am", house: 3 } 
              ] 
            } 
          , { id: 2, shows: 
              [ { index: 3, datetime: "9 Nov, Mon - 2:00pm",   house: 1 } 
          ] } ] 
        } 
      , { branchName: "City Cinema - Los Angeles"
        , movies: 
          [ { id: 2, shows: 
              [ { index: 4, datetime: "11 Nov, Wed - 9:00am",  house: 4 } 
              , { index: 5, datetime: "11 Nov, Wed - 11:00am", house: 2 } 
          ] } ] 
        } 
      , { branchName: "City Cinema - Wisconsin"
        , movies:
          [ { id: 1, shows: 
              [ { index: 6, datetime: "11 Nov, Wed - 9:00am", house: 4} 
      ] } ] } ] 


  const Movies = 
    [ { id        : 1
      , type      : "now"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"
      , src       : "../yy.mp4"
      , name      : "Casablanca"
      , cast      : "Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergmen"
      , director  : "Michael Curtiz"
      , duration  : 120
      } 
    , { id        : 2
      , type      : "now"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"
      , src       : "../xx.mp4"
      , name      : "Chocalate"
      , cast      : "Christiano Roland, Wayne Beckman"
      , director  : "Alex Curtis"
      , duration  : 110
      } 
    , { id        : 3
      , type      : "now"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"
      , src       : "../xx.mp4"
      , name      : "Wildlife"
      , cast      : "Marcus Randford"
      , director  : "David De Geek"
      , duration  : 100
      } 
    , { id        : 4
      , type      : "upcoming"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"
      , src       : "../xx.mp4"
      , name      : "Barbecue"
      , cast      : "Taylor Watson"
      , director  : "Rolando Broom"
      , duration  : 105
      } 
    , { id        : 5
      , type      : "upcoming"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"
      , src       : "../xx.mp4"
      , name      : "BigBuck"
      , cast      : "Mark Hughes"
      , director  : "Tim Carlton"
      , duration  : 115
      } 
    , { id        : 6               // <--
      , type      : "upcoming"
      , thumbnail : "../xx.png"     // <--
      , src       : "../xx.mp4"
      , name      : "Nature"
      , cast      : "Benjamin Crook"
      , director  : "Memphis Delan"
      , duration  : 100
      } 
    ] 

const DomParser  = new DOMParser()
  ,   cinemaSlct = document.getElementById("cinemaSelect")
  ,   div_lm     = document.querySelector('div#lm')

Cinemas.forEach((cinema,index) =>
  { cinemaSlct.add( new Option( cinema.branchName, index )) });

cinemaSlct.onchange = () =>
  {
  div_lm.innerHTML = ""
  Cinemas[cinemaSlct.value].movies.forEach(movieC=>
    {
    movieC.shows.forEach(show=>
      {
      let movie = Movies.find(x=>x.id===show.index)
      if (!movie) throw 'no movie reference' 

      let newSection = `
  <section>
    <hr>
    <img src="${movie.thumbnail}" alt="${movie.name}">
    <p>name : ${movie.name} <br>
      cast : ${movie.cast} <br>
      director : ${movie.director} </p>
    <hr>
    <p> datetime:${show.datetime} <br>   house:${show.house} </p>
    <hr>
  </section>`;
      div_lm.appendChild( (DomParser.parseFromString( newSection, 'text/html')).body.firstChild )
      })
    })
  }
```

```html
<div id="Cinema">
  <form id="cin" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Cinema</legend>
      <select id="cinemaSelect">
        <option value="" selected disabled> select one</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="lm"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply ! But if jQuery is not allowed, do you have any ideas on how to run the loop of the array by using only JavaScript ? Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin there is no jQuery in my code.Everything is pure JS. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I see I see. Thanks for your clarification ! I am new to the language and still kinda confused about it lmao. Thank you so much :D Have a nice day.